# removing a part of a polygon makes the entire thing not render

Tags: polygons, openscad

So, I make a prism:

```
width=30
thickness=15
polyhedron(
    points=[ 
        [width,0,0],[width,0,thickness],
        [width,width,0],[width,width,thickness],
        [0,width,0],[0,width,thickness]
    ],
    faces=[
        [1,3,5], [0,2,4],[1,0,2,3],[3,5,4,2],[1,5,4,0]
        ]
    );
```

Which renders just fine: 
[image]

Then, I remove a chunk of it:

```
difference () {
    <THAT PRISM>
    translate([0,0,thickness-5]) cylinder(r=width-10, h=6);
    }
```

what I get is, instead of a prism with a circular chunk taken out of it, I get a non-complete polygon:[image]
Whats up with that?  What am I doing wrong with the difference statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your faces are mis-orientated, see [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/The_OpenSCAD_Language#polyhedron_-_polygon_orientation_issues). The order of the points must be clockwise when looking from outside. Here the correct faces:

```
faces=[
    //[1,3,5], [0,2,4],[1,0,2,3],[3,5,4,2],[1,5,4,0]
    [1,5,3],[0,2,4],[0,1,3,2],[3,5,4,2],[0,4,5,1]
    // edit 27.07.2015 order of faces changed
    ]
```

edit 27.07.2015:

with Your faces there should be an output in console like this:

```
Top level object is a 3D object:
Simple: no
Vertices: 15
Halfedges: 30
Edges: 15
Halffacets: 4
Facets: 2
Volumes: 1
WARNING: Object may not be a valid 2-manifold and may need repair! 
Rendering finished.
```

"Simple: no" and the warning are hints , that Your polyhedron is invalid. If the object is valid, it would be "Simple: yes" without any warning.

Comment: Well, that fixed the problem, but still confuses me why it ever rendered into a working polyhedron.

Comment: As 4 faces are mis-orientated, only your bottom is correct, the result only looks like a polyhedron, but there is no "working polyhedron". So the cylinder can only cut 1 shape but not a 3D-object.

Answer (score 0):

If your polygon is not too much complex, you can sometimes wrap it in "hull" to ensure that it's "solid".

Keeping your code, and adjusting the style and the position of the cylinder and wrapping the polygon in "hull", we got :

```
width = 30;
thickness = 15;

difference() {
  hull() {
    polyhedron (
      points = [
        [width, 0, 0], [width, 0, thickness],
        [width, width, 0], [width, width, thickness],
        [0, width, 0], [0, width, thickness]
      ],
      faces = [
        [1,3,5], [0, 2, 4],
        [1, 0, 2, 3], [3, 5, 4, 2], [1, 5, 4, 0]
      ]
    );
  }
  translate([0, 0, thickness - 5]) cylinder(r = width, h = 6);
}
```

That renders and previews as :

[image]

[OpenSCAD manual - hull](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/Transformations#hull)